# How can I change the value returned from a SELECT inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

My stored procedure is returning the following:

```
    DECLARE @AnswerGridCorrect VARCHAR(20)
    ...
    ...
    SELECT  @AnswerGridResponses AS AnswerGridResponses,
            @AnswerGridCorrect AS AnswerGridCorrect,
            @Authenticated As Authenticated,
            @RC AS RC,
            @Result AS Result
```

How can I make it return a `NULL` for `@AnswerGridCorrect` if `@Result = 'F'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

You can do this using a switch case statement.

#### Sample

```
DECLARE @AnswerGridCorrect VARCHAR(20)
...
...
SELECT  @AnswerGridResponses AS AnswerGridResponses,
        CASE @Result
           WHEN 'F' THEN null
           ELSE @AnswerGridCorrect 
        END AS AnswerGridCorrect,
        @Authenticated As Authenticated,
        @RC AS RC,
        @Result AS Result
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Could I also use your way of doing the case statement first for this code? SET  @Authenticated = (SELECT CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)